# Auto fill container CSS Bootstrap with Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am kinda new to bootstrap and am trying to figure out how to fill-out an container with images which differ from sizes.

Currently I am using the background-image tag but I would like to change this to an image tag, this looks like:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-push-2 overlay">
        <div class="container-fluid image-library">
            <div class="col-lg-4 image-container" style="background-image: url('media/placeholder/1.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 image-container" style="background-image: url('media/placeholder/2.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 image-container" style="background-image: url('media/placeholder/3.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    .image-container{
    height: 200px; 
    max-width:300px;
    outline: #FFFFFF solid; 
    background-position: center center; 
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;        
}
```

After that I would like the column of Bootstrap to center this, but I cant seem to make this work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Greetings,

Bram

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add

```
background-size:100%;
or
background-size:auto;
```

to your .image-container class?

Comment: To what end? I would like to change the whole "background class" to an html img tag. When I add your suggestion nothing big changes :(.

Comment: the solution from @mrid is perfect.

Comment: Appreciate the response btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `img` tag since you wanted to shift to it.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h7p0dghb/1/)

HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-push-2 overlay">
    <div class="container-fluid image-library">
        <div class="col-lg-4 image-container" ><img src="http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 image-container" ><img src="http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 image-container"><img src="http://logonoid.com/images/stack-overflow-logo.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.image-container{
    height: 200px; 
    max-width:300px;
    outline: #FFFFFF solid; 
    background: red;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;        
}

.image-container img{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/UDqlA

is what I get, I want the images to fill out the whole container + spacing between those containers and centering the content (the centering part seems to work nice).